# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: 6

I have two custom modules: 1. oldmpp   2. newmpp (copying from oldmpp but modifying some parts). This method works for my other custom modules. But this time, it gave me this error:

```
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ' filterrekkor_mppnew' not found or invalid function name in D:\d6\includes\form.inc on line 378.
```

In old modules, this function named "filterrekkor_mpp". So, in new module, I rename to "filterrekkor_mppnew"

I've already tried to rename function to: "mppnew_filtrek", but the error still the same.

What should I do? Thanks for your help...

Comment: Could you also post the part of your code where the Form API callback is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, it was caused by name of function. I renamed to " filterrekkor_mppnew" (white space in the beginning) :X

Solved after 5 days just to realize for white space! OMG!